# Headless UI & React Dropdown menu changing position when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I want to create a dropdown menu, for which I'm using HeadlessUI on React with Tailwind.

The menu is working fine, except that when clicked on, the position of the menu changes, as in instead of dropping down perfectly from the menu button it overlays it (I don't know how to describe it exactly).

Here's a before and after, hope you can make out what I'm trying to say:

[Before button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60tcO.png)
[After the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoW7e.png)

The code for the dropdown menu:

```
function HomeMenu(props) {
return (
<Menu>
  <Menu.Button>{props.name}</Menu.Button>
  
  <Transition
    enter="transition duration-100 ease-out"
    enterFrom="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
    enterTo="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
    leave="transition duration-75 ease-out"
    leaveFrom="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
    leaveTo="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
  ></Transition>


  <Menu.Items>
    <Menu.Item>
      {({ active }) => (
        <a href="/account-settings">
          Account settings
        </a>
      )}
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>
      {({ active }) => (
        <a href="/account-settings">
          Logout
        </a>
      )}
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu.Items>
</Menu>
  )
  }
```

The div in which the menu is used:

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center p-6">
      <h1 className="text-6xl px-3 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-lmgray">
          NEW STREET JOURNAL
      </h1>
      <div className="absolute right-20 mt-2 px-5 rounded-md border-2 border-gray shadow-lg py-1 bg-lmgray" >
        <HomeMenu name={props.name}/>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="absolute right-20 mt-2 px-5 rounded-md border-2 border-gray shadow-lg py-1 bg-lmgray" >
        <HomeMenu name={props.name}/>
      </div>
```

try to remove the classname **absolute** and try again

Comment: Hi, thanks but that did not work. Also, I'm using absolute to get the menu to remain stuck to the right, so I reckon the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).